# Is there a way to relativize Blockchain ledger copies?

Tags: distributed-computing, blockchain

I have a few philosophical questions about Blockchain:

Current Bitcoin's blockchain size is over 150gb, right?

When a new peer joins a blockchain network it has to download the full copy of the ledger, right?

I am wondering if is there a way possible in blockchain where a participant Peer does not need to be forced to have a full copy?

I am having these thoughts because it would be nice if low-end devices could join the network without having this huge storage capacity requirement, imagine how great would be having smartphones and IoT devices contributing to the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting thought. Blockchain platforms like Bitcoin are not meant to be running in low-end devices. If you are a non-miner, why would you care to spend 150gig of your memory in storing and validating blocks.

Blockchain solutions like IOTA that uses Directed Acyclic Graphs allows you to be a full node or a partial node, where you can opt to store full blockchain or not. It is meant for small devices who want to be a part of the chain without having to store full data.